# Dynamically change frame colour tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

Need to dynamically change bg of `tk.Frame.__init__` when `self.darkMode()` is activated

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bg="white")
        self.grid()
        root.title("redacted")
        root.geometry("260x160")
        root.resizable(0, 0)
        self.createWidgets()
        rows = 0
        while rows < 50:
            root.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
            root.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
            rows += 1
    ...

    def darkMode(self):
        self.question.config(bg="#404040", fg="white")
        self.answercheck.config(bg="#404040", fg="white")
        self.ocontinue.config(highlightbackground="#404040")
        self.option1.config(highlightbackground="#404040", highlightthickness=2)
        self.option2.config(highlightbackground="#404040", highlightthickness=2)
        self.option3.config(highlightbackground="#404040", highlightthickness=2)
        self.option4.config(highlightbackground="#404040", highlightthickness=2)
        self.QUIT.config(highlightbackground="#404040")
        root.config(bg="#404040")
```

Comment: Have you tried `self.config(bg="#404040")` since `Application` is inherits from the Frame class?

Comment: @j_4321 that solved it, can't believe didn't think of that. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved by j_4321 in comment. `self.config(bg="#404040")`